# How to redirect by selecting an option value of datalist in php?

Tags: php

i am new in php. As we use ajax for searching in php, in similar way we use datalist in .net, now i want to use datalist in php too. Do u have any idea how can we do that? but now the problem is "how to redirect to another page by selecting an option value"?
Code is as below:

```
 <input type="text" list="gt"  />
  <datalist name="dt" id="gt" >
   <?php
   while($result33=mysqli_fetch_assoc($select33))
   {
   ?>
   <option value="artistdetail.php?id=<?php echo $result33['ID']; ?>"> <?php echo    $result33['name']; ?> </option>

  <?php
  }
  ?>
  </datalist>
```

Comment: want to pass Id and Name?

Comment: i just want to redirect on the page as mentioned in option value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<option value="artistdetail.php?id=<?php echo $result33['ID']; ?>"> <?php echo    $result33['name']; ?> <? echo ("onclick='location.href='artistdetail.php?id=$result33[ID]';");?> </option>
```